# Check file is available or not in android?

Tags: android

I use the below code to create a file in my application.I need to check is the file is exist or not from my code ? Help me

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null;        
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    String data="My file Test ";  
    try{
        fOut = openFileOutput("settings.dat",MODE_PRIVATE);     
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();           
        }
        catch (Exception e) {      
        e.printStackTrace();          
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [`File.exists()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) method?

> ```
>   public boolean exists()
> ```
>
> Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname
>    exists.
>
> **Returns:**`true` if and only if the file or directory denoted
>             by this abstract pathname exists; `false` otherwise

(Basically, you would do something like `if (new File("settings.dat").exists()) { ... }`.)

Otherwise, you could go through [`Context.fileList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList%28%29) and look for the file there.